# How can I call javascript function using a foreach on a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, callback, call

My problem is pretty easy to understand. I have a JSON object (see code) and I will automatically call all functions of this object in the order that those appears. 
.

```
var installer = {
    a : function() {
          ...
        }
    b : function() {
          ...
        }
};

for(var func in installer) {
    fn.call(document);
};
```

Have you any idea why the previous code doesn't work ? I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in javascript.

Thanks in advance !

Regards.

Comment: You do **not** have a JSON object. You have a normal JS object defined with object literal notation: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `var func` as the variable to loop through the members of `installer`, yet you use `fn.call(...)`. Where did `fn` come from?

Should you be able to do: `installer[func].call(document)` instead of `fn.call(document)`.

Also your functions declared in the installer object don't take any arguments, yet you're passing `document` as an argument.

[updated code to add missing `.call` to `installer[func](document)`]

Comment: `call` alters the variable `this`, so you can simply use `this` in the function body to reference `document`.

Comment: Thanks !! You're right, this is a simple JS Object and I can use installer[func](document).

Comment: The last sentence is not correct. Please read about call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. `installer[func](document)` and `installer[func].call(document)` are two different statements.

Comment: Thanks for your remark and fir the link too ! You're right, I'm wrong, for now I'm using intaller[func].call();

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a variable called `fn`, and you are also missing commas at the end of your function definitions.

Additionally, your functions will not be called in order because JavaScript orders your object properties arbitrarily. You may want to consider using an array or, as I have done below, specify an array that determines the order.

```
var installer = {
    a : function() {
          ...
        },
    b : function() {
          ...
        },
};

var order = [ "a", "b" ];

for(var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
    installer[order[i]].call(document);
}
```

Comment: I assume document is the HTML document, a global var available in a desktop browser's JavaScript environment

Comment: This does not guarantee the functions will get executed in the order they are defined.

Comment: Never iterate arrays with `for...in`. And if you do, then the variable is the index of the array, not the value... so your code is still wrong.